# MFMailComposeViewController Not Working in Landscape

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My app uses landscape mode. When trying to integrate MFMailComposeViewController that always worked for me in my other portrait mode apps, I came across the issue of mail controller not showing up at all. I found a lot of info during research and I tried to overwrite MFMailComposeViewController like it suggests here:

[mfmailcomposeviewcontroller in landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518499/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-landscape)

However, it still acts the same way. In short, my View-based app has a main controller A and other controllers B and C, for example. B is open on top of A and it has the MFMailComposeViewController which, when running, hides B and goes back to A.

This is very strange but I feel like it has to do with view hierarchy and where exactly I need to add MFMailComposeViewController. When overwritten (as in a link above), this code does not resolve my problem:

```
MailCompose *controller = [[MailCompose alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

I appreciate any additional suggestions.

Here is the code I am using:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

    MailCompose *picker = [[MailCompose alloc]init];


    //MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];//was before I subclassed
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"info@site.com"]];
    [picker setSubject:@"Feedback"];

    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    picker.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Comment: I have an app which allows you to rotate to any orientation you like, and I send mail using the standard MFMailComposeViewController without any issues whatsoever. It works in portrait or landscape and rotations done while the mail view is open are passed back successfully to the underlying views. 

The post you have linked to is about preventing rotation of the view while the mail composer is frontmost. That doesn't sound like the problem you are having here. Can you show the code where you call the composer?

Comment: I just added code I am using. And it does work for my portrait view app. Thanks

Comment: What is MailCompose? Your subclass of MFMailViewComposeViewController?

Comment: yes, it is. Exactly the same one as in the link I provide to another post. But even using no subclass results in the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have for calling the composer looks spot on, but you already know that. So it can only be something like:

- the code is never called
- the device isn't sending mail

(these two can be checked with the debugger)

- you are presenting this view from the wrong place, eg from a view that is already presenting a modal view controller (didn't know if this was possible?)
- you have added a new window to the app at alert or status bar level, this will obscure the composer when it is presented.

Bit of a set of guesses, I hope one of them works for you!

Comment: The 1, 2 and 4 are not possible. I verified. But #3 is worth checking. However, again, my other app in portrait mode is using the same code and it works brilliantly.

Comment: Here is how this view is added: viewB = [[AboutViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ABoutViewController" bundle:nil]; /*skipping frame code*/  [self.view addSubview:viewB.view]; //and later viewB is calling mail composer code. What's wrong here?

Comment: AND just to confirm the code is right, when I remove landscape mode set up in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation returning YES, my mail opens up without problems. Works brilliantly!

Comment: You shouldn't add another viewcontrollers view as a subview, you should present that view controller modally or push it using navigationcontroller. No idea if that is linked to your mail issues though, sorry.

Comment: Are you saying I should never do something like [self.view addSubview:viewB.view];? If so, why? It's a view based app.

Comment: Because by doing so you're corrupting the view controller hierarchy. View B is now a child of view A but view controller B is not a child of view controller A. This could explain why orientation events are not being passed to your mail composer.