# disable landscape mode in mailViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I disabled landscape mode with following code in my app. :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);


}
```

But when mail view shows it somehow enables land landscape mode.

code of mail action:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
            {
                MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
                mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
                [mailer setSubject:@"Subject 1"];
                UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_v22.png"];
                NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
                [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"mobiletutsImage"];
                NSString *emailBody = @"Test ";
                [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

                [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];


            }
```

**Main question:** how to disable landscape mode in mailView?

---

*Additional question*: how to change color of buttons in mailView? (Cancel button and send button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is subclass the MFMailViewController and override it's orientation. There is a good example here: [MFMailComposeViewController in landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518499/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-landscape) you'll just have to change it to suit your desired orientation.

edit: It's basically because the view controller has this mode enabled by default, it is not derived from your main view controller, hence the need to subclass it

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a more correct solution for you. Hope that helps